# Query succesful alone, fails randomly when inside application with "Associated statement not prepared"

Tags: python, .net, sql-server, flask, pyodbc

I've got a set of statements to fetch data. The query itself seems to work fine, but when run inside an application several times in quick succession, some of the queries fail. I have very limited information on the interaction of each of the components, so I'd like to start by just stating some things.

#### Statements

Here are some of the technologies in play:

- SQL Server, using Microsoft's ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server
- Python with pyodbc handling the databases, Flask serving on localhost
- VB/C#.NET application calling the Python

And some properties of the system:

- Database connections are pooled (pyodbc default)
- A new cursor is created and disposed of for every executed query
- Python is neither multithreaded nor in multiple processes
- .NET **is** multithreaded it being a web service, the calls to Python within are made in a few concurrent batches

#### Code

Here's a gist of the kind of queries made:

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Result TABLE (ID int unique not null, fields int varchar etc.);

--------- Base information ----------

INSERT INTO @Result (ID, subset of fields)
SELECT c.ID and various fields from joined tables
WHERE conditions hold

--------- Concatenated field --------

UPDATE @Result
SET Concat = r.Concat
FROM (
    SELECT o.ID AS ide, STUFF((
        SELECT ' ' + t.ID
        FROM various tables
        FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
    ) AS Concat
    WHERE conditions hold
) r
WHERE conditions hold;

SELECT * FROM @Result;
```

And the results are read in Python like so:

```
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(q)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
    columns = [(c[0], c[1]) for c in cursor.description]
```

#### Problem

This is the error I get with a few calls during one execution of the batches:

> [HY007] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Associated statement is not prepared (0) (SQLNumResultCols)

**Do you have any idea what is at play here?** I was not able to find any similar case, and even the information on the error itself is scarce. The best thing I could find was [this forum post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/security/en-US/3db9d509-de7b-4610-8f14-8ef346e314e3/wrong-error-message-associated-statement-is-not-prepared?forum=sqldataaccess).

---

For additional context, prior to creating a new cursor on every call and connecting with a [MARS connection](https://github.com/catherinedevlin/ipython-sql/issues/54) I was receiving different errors:

> [HY000] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Connection is busy with results for another command (0) (SQLExecDirectW)
>
> ('HY000', 'The driver did not supply an error!')
>
> [HY010] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Function sequence error (0) (SQLRowCount)

#### Disclaimer

I'm aware that this is not exactly a reproducable situation. However I feel like the problem is such that a more experienced developer may very well already have solved a similar issue. In the very possible absence of clear answers, I'd appreciate any pointers on starting to solve this.

## Edit

#### New connections and no pooling

The new routine for a query would be:

```
connection = pyodbc.connect(**keywords)
with connection.cursor() as cursor:
    cursor.execute(q)
    rows = cursor.fetchall()
connection.close()
```

Creating a new connection for every call without connection pooling first results in a number of successful calls, but by the end of the batch gives an operational error.

> pyodbc.OperationalError: ('08001', '[08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Encryption not supported on the client. (21) (SQLDriverConnect); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Client unable to establish connection (21); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]Invalid connection string attribute (0); [08001] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver 17 for SQL Server]A network-related or instance-specific error has occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server. Server is not found or not accessible. Check if instance name is correct and if SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections. For more information see SQL Server Books Online. (0)')

This error seems bizarre taking into account the fact that the connection was made successfully many times before with exactly the same keyword arguments.

#### Flask app factory

Using a new connection every time and creating an app inside an application factory function instead of a global file results in a successful run of the whole batch! However, removing either one of these two changes brings the original error back. Connection pooling was not a problem.

So indeed I got it working, but it remains a mystery what exactly caused this, because I wasn't able to narrow it down enough.

Comment: How do you create connection? Try creating new one every time. Make sure all ODBC resources are released.

Comment: @PawełDyl It did work when combined with using the Flask application factory. Edits above.